# How to create single class object when using django-celery?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, celery

I am using celery beat schedule to automatically reset an attribute at midnight. And after that I also want to send notification to all the relevant users using firebase. So, I have written following code.

```
def send_notification(reg_ids, data_message):

    push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=fcm_config['GCM_API_KEY'])
    push_service.multiple_devices_data_message(registration_ids=reg_ids, data_message=message)


@shared_task 
def reset_daily_count():

    try:
        User.objects.all().update(daily_attempts=3)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(e)
    else:
        send_notification(reg_ids, data_message)
```

But this code will create the `FCMNotification` object, every time I will call it. What I want is to create a single object and access it from somewhere, whenever needed, even for other celery tasks, not only periodic task but normal tasks as well. How will I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an object where you define class and import it wherever you want like this.

```
class FCMNotification:
    pass
    # daclaration


push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=fcm_config['GCM_API_KEY'])
```

You can use `push_service` in celery tasks as well as normal code like this.

```
from <PATH> import push_service
```

Comment: Will it not create separate push_service instance everytime I will call the import statement? Basically my question is when will this push_service will get destroyed?

Comment: Also, if I Import push_service in different files, will it create different objects of `FCMNotification` or will it be same?

Comment: `push_service` will refer to same object no matter how many times it is imported. It will be created when imported somewhere for the first time. I think (not sure) it will create separate objects for django and celery processes. But for one process it will refer to same object. And will be destroyed when process stopped.

Comment: Yes it will create separate object for each process

Comment: I checked and it is creating 2 objects(because each has 2 processes) each for django server, celery worker and celery beat. So yeah, it creates different objects for each process but maintains it for the process. Thanks!!!